# how to take input in a function that will be a variable in that function?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a function that will allow me to loop through a user input if it is not an integer but if it is, break. Here, the variable which will take the input cannot be same each time the function is called.

```
def intry():
    global a # intry(b) should change global a to global b
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(raw_input())  # intry(b) should do b = int(raw_input())
        except ValueError:
            print 'Try again'
        else:
            return a  # expecting return b


intry()

intry()

print a + a  # then i can print a + b
```

As you can probably understand by the comments of the above code, the input in the function actually does not change the results but the variable. If no input is given, the variables should be 'a' or anything by default

Comment: sorry if it is hard to understand because for some reason the indentation of the code did not remain the same when i posted this

Comment: please use code-formatting options available.

Comment: I think this is a convoluted way of summing two integers from raw_input. Why would you need to do it this way?

Comment: Gianluca Micchi. if I simply take an integer as an input and the user gives a string, then it will show an error. So I have defined this function which will not accept any string as an input and ask you to try again

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your function but you are not storing or using  a result of the function, I you really want to do with your code you can do it like:

```
print (intry()+intry())
```

or:

```
a = intry()
b = intry()

print (a + b)
```

output:

```
23
4
27
```

full code :

```
def intry():
    while True:
        try:
            a = raw_int(input("enter number:"))
        except ValueError:
            print ('Try again')
        else:
            return a

print (intry()+intry())
```

output:

```
enter number:3
enter number:4
7
```